How can I get a new marker position without changing the camera solve?
I have a motion tracking camera solve that I'm happy with and have aligned a large amount of scene geometry to.  I found out I want to add a few more markers to determine where a new object should go.  After tracking these markers, how can I figure out their 3D positions without affecting the camera solve?

Select the trackers you want to identify, and press the "Link Empty to track" button.

If you need to include the new tracker in the solver without affecting the results, you can lower its "Weight" value.


That creates empties each with a "Follow Track" constraint attached to the associated track.  If I do this with existing markers, I can then check the "3D Position" checkbox in that constraint to show the 3D location of the marker.  However, if I do this with my new markers, the 3D position is just shown as the origin.  Presumably this is because I haven't solved the 3D positions of the markers.  How can I solve the 3D positions of these new markers without disturbing my camera solve?  That's the main subject of this question.

I updated my answer.

Weighting the new markers to 0 seems good.  It seems like it would be nice to be able to "lock" the camera solve and compute new markers' 3d positions, but it seems like there isn't an easier way to do that
